# Help with remote controlling

Tags: server, ssh, 17.10

So I want to be able to connect to my laptop running Ubuntu Server 17.10 without having to log in to another session. I may be logging in with the same user, but if I am running something like a Minecraft server, instead of having to run upstairs just to change something, I want to be able to control it from my computer. I set up SSH on my laptop to remote control it but it instead put me in a different session, rather than the same one. Is there any way to remote control my laptop with the same session?

Thanks!

-Mike M

Comment: Look in to screen, tmux, byobu.

Comment: I'm sorry but can you explain a little bit better?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1056476/how-can-i-control-my-minecraft-server-when-i-run-it-at-boot-with-a-rc-local-scri

Comment: Sure! If you can post an answer detailing what you did, it would be great!

Comment: Sorry for posting late. After I figured it out I had to go. I posted the answer but it won't let me mark it as answer until 2 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Thanks to Muru for helping me!)
There is a thing called `tmux` which you can use to create sessions. All I had to do was create a session on one device using `tmux new -s [session name]` and on the remote controlling device, type `tmux attach -t [session name]`.

Now I can control my Minecraft server without having to walk upstairs to look at my laptop!